# How to make a popover non-modal?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to have popovers over console.log(), helloword(), and others. However, since popovers in MUI are modal, I cannot show other popovers unless I click outside the popover that is currently opened.

Is there a way to disable modal behavior?

[image: Usage Scenario]

So far, I forced non-modality via properties:

```
    style ={{width:0, height:0}}
    modal={null}
    hideBackdrop={true}
    disableBackdropClick={true}
    disableAutoFocus={true}
    disableEnforceFocus={true}
```

What about a modal={true|false}?

Comment: That is precisely the point, a popover is not inherently modal. For instance, a dialog is inherently modal. Autocompletes, suggestions, or code completions are non-modal, yet they are popovers.